# add reference for system.net.http in c# visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How can I get visual studio 2012 to use the namespace for

```
using System.Net.http;
```

I can't find any solution for it. (direct solution)

Answer (score 3):

You should add a referenc to `System.Net.Http.dll` from your project. To do this in your `Solution Explorer` Right Click your `References` then click `Add Reference`.Search for `System.Net.Http`, add it to your references. Then you can use `"using System.Net.Http;"`

See the documentation for more details: [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: yes. i understand. but then i can't find any reference for the system.net.http.dll. can u teach me how to get it? so that i can add the reference?

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Net.Http` namespace is only available in .NET Framework 4.5.  Make sure that your project is targeting .NET 4.5 and then try adding it from the references dialog.

To change the project configuration, right-click the project in solution explorer and click `Properties`.  Go to the `Application` tab and select the desired framework in the `Target Framework` combo box.

[image]

Comment: how to i make sure my project is targeting .NET 4.5? can teach?

Comment: Edited answer to include details.

Comment: but mine 1 . the target framework. i spoint to android version.
not the framework. so i can't add the reference,,

Comment: When you say "the Android version", which version are you referring to?  There are several companies that have published .NET-compatibility libraries for Android.

Comment: 2.2 . i try another version like 3.0 . also dont have the net